# Get rid of chrome new tab page ad

Tags: google-chrome

So, recently, on the Chrome new tab page, the message "Get a Chromebook for the holidays"  has started to appear. ([Others](http://9to5google.com/2011/11/21/google-begins-advertising-holiday-chromebook-sale-right-inside-of-chromes-new-tab-page/) have witnessed similar behavior)

[image]

I want to know how I am supposed to get rid of it. Clicking the "X" is not a permanent solution.

Comment: I use Chrome all the time, I don't get this ad, default startup procedure.

Comment: I'm sorry, I accidentially clicked on edit. I don't know how I can remove it :-/

Answer (score 1):

With the [Speed Dial extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi) you can customize the new tab page to have links to whatever pages you want. This replaces the default new tab page, which will eliminate any ads you might be seeing.