# What can Google "insert" into Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Always when I've opened a new tab, I've got a little notice "Get A Chromebook For The Holidays" ([Screenshot](http://9to5google.com/2011/11/21/google-begins-advertising-holiday-chromebook-sale-right-inside-of-chromes-new-tab-page/)) for some days. How could Google insert this advertising into Chrome? What can they also add to Chrome?

Was it perhaps an updated?

I am asking because I think it would be a bit scary if Google could directly communicate with Chrome (and this setting would be activated by default).

Comment: I do not get such advertisements. What did you do before they started? Could this be an extension/app?

Comment: @CarighanMaconar - It is confirmed that it is not an extension. Google a bit, you'll stumble onto a link or two mentioning it. Sucks, but what can one do.

Comment: @Idigas Use chromium !

Comment: See also ["Get rid of chrome new tab page ad"](http://superuser.com/questions/359931/).

Comment: Use SRWare Iron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a new tab, and right-click in the new tabe then View Source.

This shows how the page is constructed.  It is just a web page with javascript that dynamically populates the page.  Such adverts would never be hard coded into the application, it wouldn't make sense to do this with a browser.  The content is pulled in from Google.

If you don't want to see the new tab page or have concerns about the data transmitted to Google, you could use the [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf) extension to create a shortcut that opens a new tab on a page of your choosing.

Comment: I guess I have to search in `var templateData`, do I?

Answer (score 0):

They can do whatever they want since automatic updating is on by default.

Comment: And it's *their* program :)

Comment: Automatic update on a Linux machine means I get notified if I want to update. They can't update without notifing me. But as I don't think that Google will add malware I update.

Comment: It's silent and automatic on OS X and Windows.